# Crystal Reports and WMF image

Tags: visual-studio, image, graphics, crystal-reports

I have a problem with inserting a vector graphics (WMF) into report (Crystal Reports v10.5 from Visual Studio 2008). The image is static, inserted  by choosing "Insert Picture" during report design in VS.

The problem is that it displays differently (size and aspect ratio) on machines with different operating systems and screen resolutions.

Converting to bitmap isn't possible beacause loss of the quality of print isn't acceptable.
I thought about dynamic loading of the image, but in this version of CR. I don't see a  possibility to set dynamic graphic location in picture properties. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: The only way how we could solve this problem was to use bitmaps. 300dpi grayscale bitmaps print almost nicely, although they increase reports [file] size substantially.

Answer (score 0):

Not right.
You must use clipboard to insert vector images in your report. For example, copy objects from CorelDraw and paste in report. Report file not grow and also work on computers without CorelDraw. Print quality is more better than any bitmaps.

PS. I think that SAP must develop native (not OLE) support of any images formats.